# How to understand this expression?

Tags: python

I am converting Hamming code from python to kotlin. And I almost did everything, but there is one expression that I do not understand.

```
error=sum(int(parity_list) * (2 ** i) for i, parity_list in enumerate(parity_list[::-1]))
```

For example: I enter the number 101

The value of the variables are obtained:

```
parity_list = [1,0]

i = 5

error = 2
```

How come `error = 2`? Can you explain the execution sequence with an example?

Program code:

```
# coding=windows-1251
 
from traceback import print_tb
 
 
print('Введите полученный код Хэмминга')
d=input()
data=list(d)
data.reverse()
c,ch,j,r,error,h,parity_list,h_copy=0,0,0,0,0,[],[],[]
 
for k in range(0,len(data)):
        p=(2**c)
        h.append(int(data[k]))
        h_copy.append(data[k])
        if(p==(k+1)):
            c=c+1
            
for parity in range(0,(len(h))):
        ph=(2**ch)
        if(ph==(parity+1)):
 
            startIndex=ph-1
            i=startIndex
            toXor=[]
 
            while(i<len(h)):
                block=h[i:i+ph]
                toXor.extend(block)
                i+=2*ph
 
            for z in range(1,len(toXor)):
                h[startIndex]=h[startIndex]^toXor[z]
            parity_list.append(h[parity])
            ch+=1
parity_list.reverse()
 
print('parity_list = ', parity_list)
print('parity_list = ', parity_list[::-1])
print('i = ', i)
error=sum(int(parity_list) * (2 ** i) for i, parity_list in enumerate(parity_list[::-1]))
print("error =  ", error)
   
if((error)==0):
        print('В полученном коде Хэмминга нет ошибок')
 
elif((error)>=len(h_copy)):
        print('Ошибка не может быть обнаружена')
 
else:
        print('Error is in',error,'bit')
 
        if(h_copy[error-1]=='0'):
            h_copy[error-1]='1'
 
        elif(h_copy[error-1]=='1'):
            h_copy[error-1]='0'
            print('После исправления код Хэмминга: - ')
        h_copy.reverse()
        print(int(''.join(map(str, h_copy))))
```

I understand how the function `for i, parity_list in enumerate(parity_list[::-1])` works, but how to add this `int(parity_list) * (2 ** i)`?

Comment: `int(parity_list)` converts `parity_list` to an integer (if it isn't already), `*` is multiplication and `(2 ** i)` is 2 to the power of `i`, what's unclear about that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm guessing it's the postfix list comprehension that he is struggling with

Comment: @Zachiah They said they understand that part...

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right @mkrieger1. The long code sample drew my eyes away (:

Comment: @mkrieger1 I know operators in python. I don't understand how to put it all together to get a number

Comment: The OP code is unnecessarily confusing because parity_list is used both the enumerated value and the List being enumerated. Use different names for different things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# Define the list
parity_list = [1, 0];
# reverse the list
reveresed_parity_list = parity_list[::-1]
# define error output as 0
error = 0
# loop through each element, getting the index and the value where i is the index and parity_list_value is the value
for i, parity_list_value in enumerate(reveresed_parity_list):
    # if i = 0 then 2^0 = 1 as the rule for any value to the exponent of 0
    error += int(parity_list_value) * (2 ** i)
```